# Playframework Slick DB Filter Operation

Tags: database, postgresql, filter, playframework, slick

Consider following two strings as records, saved in column C1.
S1: "MyValue1 - myValue2"
S2: "MyValue1 - myValue2 - myValue3"

Following query will list above strings without any filter operations.

```
play.Logger.info("projectList: " + ((for { t <- Table } yield t).map{_.C1}.list))
```

**Question:** I want to filter the list by number of hyphens ('-')

I tried following query but It's not working correctly

```
play.Logger.info("projectList: " + ((for { t <- Table if (t.C1.toString().split("-").length == someLength } yield t).map{_.C1}.list))
```

where **someLength** equals either 2 or 3. Any idea of using string operations as filter in slick DB for playframework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

toString is not a Slick method. Once you use it you leave the realm of database queries and operate on the client side in a way you are probably not expecting. Here are all supported methods: http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.1.0/api/#scala.slick.lifted.StringColumnExtensionMethods

You can probably do it like this:

`.filter(t => (t-size - t.replace("-","").size) === someLength)`

Answer (score 0):

I used .filter to use string operations. Thanks @cvogt for the help though.

**Solution:**

```
((for { t <- Table } yield t).list.filter{ t => t.split("-").length == someLength})
```